# Upgrade to 16.04 breaks USB SD card reader: how to fix?

Tags: usb

I have an external USB 3.0 Lexar Multi-card reader which I mainly use to transfer images on an SD Card from my camera into Shotwell. This all worked fine under 15.10: back in the good old days, the card was immediately detected on insertion into the reader, Shotwell launched, the new image files were presented, all by default.

I updated to 16.04 and this stopped working.

I have tried:

```
sudo sh -c "apt-add-repository restricted; apt-get update; apt-get  install linux-generic linux-firmware linux-firmware-nonfree"
```

(linux-firmware-nonfree does not exist, ineffective)

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan'
```

(this has no apparent effect)

The various troubleshooting outputs requested in similar questions:

lsusb:

```
    Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:288f Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0b95:772b ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772B
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lspci -v:

```
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
Subsystem: Dell 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
Memory at d0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Subsystem: Dell 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at d051a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci


00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Subsystem: Dell 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
Memory at d0519000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
```

dmesg:

```
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.4.0-38-generic (buildd@lgw01-58) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) ) #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 (Ubuntu 4.4.0-38.57-generic 4.4.19)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.0-38-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

dmesg | grep usb:

```
    [    0.181730] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
    [    0.181740] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
    [    0.181759] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
    [    1.054245] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
    [    1.054247] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    1.054249] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
    [    1.054251] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.4.0-38-generic ehci_hcd
    [    1.054253] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
    [    1.070363] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
    [    1.070368] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    1.070371] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
    [    1.070372] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.4.0-38-generic ehci_hcd
    [    1.070374] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
    [    1.072355] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
    [    1.072358] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    1.072360] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
    [    1.072361] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 4.4.0-38-generic xhci-hcd
    [    1.072363] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
    [    1.073079] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
    [    1.073081] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    1.073083] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
    [    1.073085] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 4.4.0-38-generic xhci-hcd
    [    1.073086] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
    [    1.366229] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
    [    1.382227] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
    [    1.382248] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
    [    1.499066] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
    [    1.499070] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
    [    1.515069] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
    [    1.515072] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
    [    1.580568] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0b95, idProduct=772b
    [    1.580572] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
    [    1.580573] usb 3-2: Product: AX88772B
    [    1.580575] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.
    [    1.580576] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 0C15E4
    [    1.770282] usb 1-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
    [    1.786257] usb 2-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
    [    1.883283] usb 2-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07da
    [    1.883286] usb 2-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
    [    2.156116] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=1bcf, idProduct=288f
    [    2.156120] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    [    2.156122] usb 1-1.5: Product: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_1.3M
    [    2.156123] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: CN01RH717248726JD80TA00
    [    7.804977] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
    [    7.870358] input: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_1.3M as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/input/input12
    [    7.870427] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
    [    9.524482] asix 3-2:1.0 eth0: register 'asix' at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, ASIX AX88772B USB 2.0 Ethernet, 00:50:b6:0c:15:e4
    [    9.524515] usbcore: registered new interface driver asix
```

Any assistance gratefully received.

Comment: Is something changing in the lsusb output if you plug/unplug the device? Moreover what is written in dmesg if you plug/unplug?

Comment: My machine is configured to check for Ubuntu's system and security updates daily, and I generally accept these uncritically. 

Happily, this problem appears to have been resolved in the past 6 days (Checking in /var/log/apt/history.log --> ? recent update of linux-firmware from 157.3 to 157.4 responsible ??).
Anyway, the expected behaviour when I plug an SD card into the external USB reader is now restored.